# Oracle SQL: What is the best way to select a subset of a very large table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have been roaming these forums for a few years and I've always found my questions had already been asked, and a fitting answer was already present.

I have a pretty generic (and maybe easy) question now though, but I haven't been able to find a thread asking the same one yet.

The situation:

- I have a payment table with 10-50M records per day, a history of 10 days and hundreds of columns. About 10-20 columns are indexed. One of the indices is batch_id.
- I have a batch table with considerably fewer records and columns, say 10k a day and 30 columns.

If I want to select all payments from one specific sender, I could just do this:

```
Select * from payments p 
where p.sender_id = 'SenderA'
```

This runs a while, even though sender_id is also indexed. So I figure, it's better to select the batches first, then go into the payments table with the batch_id:

```
select * from payments p
where p.batch_id in 
(select b.batch_id from batches where b.sender_id = 'SenderA')
--and p.sender_id = 'SenderA'
```

Now, my questions are:

- In the second script, should I uncomment the Sender_id in my where clause on the payments table? It doesn't feel very efficient to filter on sender_id twice, even though it's in different tables.
- Is it better if I make it an inner join instead of a nested query?
- Is it better if I make it a common table expression instead of a nested query or inner join?

I suppose it could all fit into one question: What is the best way to query this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Comment: How many rows are returned by the query?

Comment: Short answers to questions:
1) If both columns(batch_id and sender_id) are indexed same way, then first simple query is more efficient.
2) Depends. In most cases Oracle will create same explain plan, so it doesn't matter.
3) Same as 2nd answer.

Few things, which might improve performance:
keep table and index statistics up-to-date
For this kind of queries single column indexes will be most efficient

Comment: Thank you. Rows returned are usually 4M or so.

Comment: Are the two tables **partitioned**? this would help a lot... also, you could try to materialize one of the two subset (`payments` or `batches` fildered for `sender_id`) using `with` construct... anyway you have to compare the execution plans to choose the form of the query.

Comment: Your "per day" numbers are a bit confusing since the queries don't have a day column and you didn't mention any partitioning. I think you're saying the PAYMENTS table has 300M rows with 100K distinct batch IDs (so 3000 rows per batch ID), but you don't say how many distinct sender IDs there are. Three? A million?

Comment: The question makes no sense, because the queries are quite different.  One uses a single table; one uses two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the worst case the two queries should run in the same time and in the best case I would expect the first query to run quicker. If it is running slower, there is some problem elsewhere. You don't need the additional condition in the second query.

The first query will retrieve index entries for a single value, so that is going to access less blocks than the second query which has to find index entries for multiple batches (as well as executing the subquery, but that is probably not significant).

But the danger as always with Oracle is that there are a lot of factors determining which query plan the optimizer chooses. I would immediately verify that the statistics on your indexed columns are up-to-date. If they are not, this might be your problem and you don't need to read any further.

The next step is to obtain a query execution plan. My guess is that this will tell you that your query is running a full-table-scan.

Whether or not Oracle choses to perform a full-table-scan on a query such as this is dependent on the number of rows returned and whether Oracle thinks it is more efficient to use the index or to simply read the whole table. The threshold for flipping between the two is not a fixed number: it depends on a lot of things, one of them being a parameter called `DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT`.

This is set-up by Orale and in theory it should be configured such that the transition between indexed and full-table scan queries should be smooth. In other words, at the transition point where your query is returning enough rows to just about make a full table scan more efficient, the index scan and the table scan should take roughly the same time.

Unfortunately, I have seen systems where this is way out and Oracle flips to doing full table scans far too quickly, resulting in a long query time once the number of rows gets over a certain threshold.

As I said before, first check your statistics. If that doesn't work, get a QEP and start tuning your Oracle instance.

Tuning Oracle is a very complex subject that can't be answered in full here, so I am forced to recommend links. Here is a useful page on the parameter: reducing it might help: [Why Change the Oracle DB_FILE_MULTIBLOCK_READ_COUNT](https://logicalread.com/oracle-db-file-multiblock-read-count-mc01/#.WnQg0q6nFaQ).

Other than that, the general Oracle performance tuning guide is here: [(Oracle) Configuring a Database for Performance](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/build_db.htm#g27214).

If you are still having problems, you need to progress your investigation further and then come up with a more specific question.

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment where you say your query is returning 4M rows out of 10M-50M in the table. If it is 4M out of 10M there is no way an index will be of any use. Even with 4M out of 50M, it is still pretty certain that a full-table-scan would be the most efficient approach.

You say that you have a lot of columns, so probably this 4M row fetch is returning a huge amount of data.

You could perhaps consider splitting off some of the columns that are not required and putting them into a child table. In particular, if you have columns containing a lot of data (e.g., some text comments or whatever) they might be better being kept outside the main table.

Remember - small is fast, not only in terms of number of rows, but also in terms of the size of each row.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer explains the problem and next steps to take well. I've been getting better at getting the information I need from a database, but I have very little knowledge about statistics and execution plans; and how to improve those. I'm always told I should ask a DBA, but those people are rare!

Comment: Reply on your edit: Indeed, there is a lot of data in the table. In my select, I'm only asking for the sender, receiver, and status. I also count the records and sum the amount. I suppose a full table scan is unavoidable. That being said, I will still have a look at the statistics.

Sadly, I don't think I have enough pull to move some columns into a child table.

Answer (score -3):

1. SQL is an declarative language. This means, that you specify what you like not how.
2. Check your indexes primary and "normal" ones...

Comment: This question deserves a wider response, since the OP clearly has a genuine performance problem.

Comment: The question was: "What is the best way to query this?" and the answer to that is: 1. SQL is an declarative language. This means, that you specify what you like not how.